# Can I filter s3 result from list_objects by tagging attribute?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

Hi I am doing something like this:

```
    paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix)
    for page in pages:
        for obj in page['Contents']:
            key = obj["Key"]
            tags = s3_client.get_object_tagging(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key)['TagSet']
            if not any(tag['Key'] == 'processed' for tag in tags):
                process(key)
                s3_client.put_object_tagging(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key, Tagging={'TagSet': [{'Key': 'processed', 'Value': 'Y'}, ]}
```

And the it run like everyday to pick up the unprocess object to process, but when the object under the bucket grow, the list become quite slow, can I filter the list object without attribut "processed"?

Answer (score 0):

You are limited to [5500 GET/HEAD requests per second per prefix](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/optimizing-performance.html). So that means that, if under your prefix you have more than 5500 objects, that's the hard limit of the number of files you can process every second.

To answer your question:

> can I filter the list object without attribut "processed"?

Not in the way you want to. You still have to do a HEAD (?) request on each file, which limits you to 5500 requests per second.

What I would recommend, if it's possible, is that you decouple that process. Using [S3 event notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/EventNotifications.html) you can send a notification on every object action to a queue. From there, you can run a small Lambda function that could do the following (just some of the possible ideas):

- Lambda checks the tag added to the object. If the object doesn't have a processed tag, add that file key to another queue from which you read on a scheduled basis and process the data, or
- Lambda checks the tag added to the object. If the object doesn't have a processed tag, add that file key to a file in an S3 bucket which will contain the list of all objects you need to process. On a scheduled basis, read that file and process the files. If any other process might process them before, you can either require that it removes the entry from the file, or you can just check the processing flag before execution for that file

Comment: Thanks but look like there is some limitation and I cannot use S3 event notifications , so I wonder can I filtering from the "list_objects_v2" so that don't need to wait a long time for loop through the folder